# Unable to view vote counts on my own deleted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, vote-count

Following some semi-recent privilege enforcement tweak, sub-10k users can no longer see vote counts on deleted posts.

However, it looks like one edge case was overlooked. If you have more than 1000 reputation, but are below 10k, you should still be able to see the vote counts of your own deleted answers.

Currently, all you get is:

[image: An error occurred during vote count fetch]

More specifically, a 404 "go away" error from `/posts/ID/vote-counts`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, > rev 2012.3.6.1480.